# Cassandra Searching for a RowKey

Tags: cassandra

I am very new to Cassandra and this time still I have not done my part on reading much about the architecture. I have a simple question for which I am not getting an answer for.

This is a sample data when I do a `list abcColumnFamily`:

```
RowKey:Message_1
=> (column=word, value=Message_1, timestamp=1373976339934001)

RowKey:Message_2
=> (column=word, value=Message_2, timestamp=1373976339934001)
```

How can I search for the Rowkey having say Message_1

In SQL world: Select * from Table where Rowkey = 'Message_1' (= OR like). I want to simply search on full string.

My intention is to just check whether a particular data of my interest is there in a rowkey or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For CQL try:

```
select * from abcColumnFamily where KEY = 'Message_1'
```

If You want to query that data using CLI try the following:

```
assume abcColumnFamily keys as utf8;
get abcColumnFamily['Message_1'];
```

Comment: I thought that the question was for an CQL solution. But You might be right that I misunderstood it. Answer updated :)

Comment: Thanks Venc! +1 Accepted. However I will also check out the CQL solution.